# Return value if column heading falls between two dates

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, lubridate

I have two dataframes `ID_list` and `Attendance`:

`ID_list` contains a list of unique IDs, their date of birth and their birthday in subsequent years of their life

```
ID DOB         Y1          Y2          Y3
1  01/05/2003  01/05/2004  01/05/2005  01/05/2006
2  05/02/2010  05/02/2011  05/02/2012  05/02/2013
3  17/06/2015  17/06/2016  17/06/2017  17/06/2018
```

`Attendance` contains a list of IDs, some of which match those in `ID_list` and percentage attendance figures at various dates:

```
ID  01/07/2010  01/07/2011  01/07/2012
4   100%        50%         75%
2   60%         40%         30%
6   80%         60%         100%
```

I would like to produce a new dataframe that contains a list of IDs and their attendance figure for each year of their life, where the dates specified in the column headings in the `Attendance` dataframe fall in between two dates in the `ID_List` dataframe. Based on the example above, it would look like this:

```
ID  Y1_att  Y2_att  Y3_att
1   NA      NA      NA
2   60%     40%     30%
3   NA      NA      NA
```

I have been trying to do this using the `%within%` and `interval` functions combined with `mutate`:

```
ID_all <- left_join(ID_list, Attendance, by = ID)
ID_all <- mutate(ID_all, Y1_att = ifelse(**column name** %within% interval(DOB, Y1), **value from column name**, NA)
```

where the values in asterisks are taken from the `Attendance` dataframe.  The idea then is to iterate through the columns take from the `Attendance` dataframe but I'm not sure how to reference a column in the `mutate` function while also using it in the calculation or if there is a better way to do this than joining the two dataframes from the start.

Comment: just to clarify in the example provided - `ID=2` has dates in `Attendance` that do not overlap with dates in `ID_list` - is that an error or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Ben thanks, it was a typo - now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do here to resolve your problem.

First, `ID_list` is not really useful as birthdays are usually separated by one year exactly, so you can retrieve the value automatically. Second, the Attendance dataset is not in the right format for what you want to achieve: it is wide (the number of columns could grow intensively) and it is easier to handle as long.

For this, you can use the new functions `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from the package `tidyr` (which were previously named `gather` and `spread`).

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

ID_list = read.table(text = "
ID DOB         Y1          Y2          Y3
1  01/05/2003  01/05/2004  01/05/2005  01/05/2006
2  05/02/2010  05/02/2011  05/02/2012  05/02/2013
3  17/06/2015  17/06/2016  17/06/2017  17/06/2018
", header=T) 

Attendance = read.table(text = "
ID  01/07/2010  01/07/2011  01/07/2012
4   100%        50%         75%
2   60%         40%         30%
6   80%         60%         100%
", header=T) 


Attendance_long = Attendance %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "date", values_to = "percent") %>% 
  mutate(date=date %>% str_remove("X") %>% str_replace_all("\\.", "/") %>% as.Date("%d/%m/%Y")) #dates as columns behave badly, needs refactoring :-(
Attendance_long

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#     ID date       percent
#  <int> <date>     <fct>  
#1     4 2010-07-01 100%   
#2     4 2011-07-01 50%    
#3     4 2012-07-01 75%    
#4     2 2010-07-01 60%    
#5     2 2011-07-01 40%    
#6     2 2012-07-01 30%    
#7     6 2010-07-01 80%    
#8     6 2011-07-01 60%    
#9     6 2012-07-01 100%
```

With the attendances in a long format, you can now join your data and compute the year number as the difference between the date of attendance and the date of birth (ceiled). Then, to achieve your expected output, you can pivot to the wide-format again and remove unnecessary columns.

```
ID_all = ID_list %>% as_tibble %>% 
  select(ID, DOB) %>% #don't need other columns
  left_join(Attendance_long, by="ID") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(DOB), as.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y") %>% 
  mutate(year = ceiling(interval(DOB, date) / years(1)),
         year = ifelse(!is.na(year), paste0("Y", year, "_att"), year))%>% 
  select(-date) %>% #important to pivot
  pivot_wider(names_from = year,
              values_from = percent) %>% 
  select(-`NA`, -DOB) 

ID_all
```

I hope it helped!